# Recording clear audio from an iPad in Audacity

Tags: audio-recording, ipad

I'm trying to record audio from my iPad running the Launchpad app. I'm using a 3.5mm Stereo Jack to 6.35mm Stereo Jack Cable lead with a 6.35mm > 3.5mm socket converter.

The quality is perfect when the sound is played through the iPad, to the PC and played through the speakers. The recorded audio is much louder and distorted.

These are my audio/quality settings:

[image]

[image]

I am aware the app allows in-app recording but I'd like to be able to mix the sounds using the Audacity software quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the input you use is the problem, i see the microphone input as the recording device. This input has a circuit that boosts the output of microphone levels. However an iPad has line level output, so try the line level input on your soundcard and change the audacity input settings.

Comment: I moved the audio cable to the Line In jack (which happened to be at the back of the PC). The audio is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the recording and playback levels are the same on the audio device.  When listening to the input through the speakers it will use the playback level for the input.  When recording from the input, it will use the recording level.  If the recording level is applying a boost, it could push the audio out of what the sound card can handle and this would result in the signal clipping.

Comment: I've tried reducing the volume on the iPad as well as the Input Volume level on Audacity. The waveform looks normal (no clipping) but the sound quality is still poor.

Comment: @Ambo100 - are you able to post samples of the audio?

Comment: Sure, It's quite clear which version is the worse quality. http://audiour.com/playlist/l1r2ky21

Comment: @Ambo100 - it doesn't sound to me like the one with the problem is the louder.  What I hear is that the second one is both quieter and sounds more heavily compressed (lacks the clarity of the first one.)  Where did those two copies come from and why can't you just import the first one directly?